Generalized variance of a multinomial distribution
Scalar variance is a univariate notion, so generalized variance gives a generalization to the multivariate setting by taking the determinant of the covariance matrix for the multivariate distribution.
However, a multinomial distribution has a singular covariance matrix, so the determinant gives minimal information about variability in the multinomial distribution; every single multinomial distribution gives the same generalized variance of zero.
However, we can drop a category from the multinomial distribution and leave it implied what would happen to the other category (as is typical when running a regression on a categorical variable). When we do that and then calculate the generalized variance, the value is not always zero.
In experimenting with this, it seems not to matter which categories we drop. Further, if we just drop row $k$ and column $k$ from the covariance matrix of the full multinomial distribution, the determinant does not seem to depend on $k$.
set.seed(2024)

# Function to calculate the covariance matrix of a multinomial distribution 
#
multinomial_cov <- function(n, p){
  
  k <- length(p)
  
  cov_np <- matrix(NA, k, k)
  for (i in 1:k){
    for (j in 1:k){
      
      if (i == j){
        cov_np[i, j] <- n * p[i] * (1 - p[j])
      }
      if (i != j) {
        cov_np[i, j] <- -n * p[i] * p[j]
      }
    }
  }
  return(cov_np)
}
#
# End of function

R1 <- 25   # Number of different multinomial parameter combinations
R2 <- 100 # Times to determine an index to remove
dets <- matrix(NA, R1, R2)
for (i in 1:R1){
  
  # Determine distribution parameters
  #
  n <- sample(seq(1, 10, 1), 1, replace = F) # Number of dice rolls
  k <- sample(seq(3, 25, 1), 1, replace = F) # How many categories, 3-25
  p <- runif(k, 0, 1); p <- p/sum(p) # Probability parameters
  
  for (j in 1:R2){
    
    # Drop a row/column (same index) from the covariance matrix
    # before calculating the determinant of the n-1 x n-1 matrix
    #
    idx <- sort(sample(seq(1, k, 1), k - 1, replace = F))
    cov_mat <- multinomial_cov(n, p)
    dets[i, j] <- det(cov_mat[idx, idx])
  }
}
apply(dets, 1, unique) # No matter the row/column removed, the determinant is
                       # the same for a given set of multinomial parameters

I seem to have done this in enough settings that I probably didn't just get lucky, so I think I have stumbled on a general fact about the multinomial distribution. What is the proof, and is this kind of determinant a useful description of variability in a multinomial distribution?

My recent interest in multinomial distributions comes from this question.

This sounds more like a property of determinants than anything particular to the multinomial.

Dropping a category appears arbitrary.  An intrinsic, relevant property of the covariance matrix is the product of its nonzero eigenvalues: use that.  A crude but simple implementation is with(svd(cov_mat), prod(d[d > 1e-8])).  For the multinomial distribution, it turns out this product will be $k$ times your principal minor determinants. //  BTW, a clearer implementation of multinomial_cov  is given by \(n,p) n * (diag(p) - outer(p, p)).

@whuber Why the product of the nonzero eigenvalues in particular? Why drop the zeros?

The zeros correspond to the null directions.

Dropping the zeros gives what we could name a generalized determinant, in complete analogy with a generalized inverse. A generalizedinberse gives an inverse restricted to the space where the matrix (qua linear operator) actually is doing something of interest, the generalized determinant a determinant of the operator restricted to that space of interest

@kjetilbhalvorsen That's right.  A standard name for this "generalized determinant" is a $k$-form. The dimension of the space of $k$-forms on a vector space of dimension $n$ is $\binom{n}{k}.$ When the support of the distribution is contained in a subspace of dimension $k,$ the dimension of the $k$-forms that do not vanish on it drops to $\binom{k}{k}=1$ and your "generalized determinant" is a basis for that space.

@whuber Is this related to a differential form?

Yes.  A differential form is a section of the bundle of k-forms on the cotangent bundle of a manifold.  Basically that means a differential form is to a form what a vector field is to a vector.
